# Where to find paykey for an order in woocommerce for adaptive payments?

Tags: paypal, woocommerce, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I created a sandbox app for my ecommerce website. I placed many orders with paypal payments. But i am not getting paykey associated with the orders, i am only getting transation id. I want to get paykey for a particular order, so if i want to refund to that order i can use that paykey for that. Where have i found that paykey associated with each order. I am using adaptive paypal payments refund api and i need paykey to refund for an order. The code is below in which i need paykey

```
curl https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Refund \
-s \
--insecure \
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: api_username" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: api_password" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: api_signature" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: NV" \
-H "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: your_app_id "   \
-d requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US \
-d payKey="where to find"
```

so can anyone tell me why i am not getting paykey for an order ?

Answer (score 1):

The pay key comes back in the response to the Pay request sent to PayPal.  Whatever plugin or code you're using for the checkout should be saving that for you in a session, in the database, or somewhere.  You'd need to track that down and make sure it's getting saved in the DB so that you can pull it when you need to.

Comment: I am using woocommerce defaul paypal checkout and dokan adaptive paypal payments plugin to do checkout process,,,,but in which db table i can find that paykey associated with the order ?

Answer (score 0):

Orders stored in `wp_posts` table where the `post_type = shop_order`.
But that only stores the basic info as Order's Title and Date with an "ID".
All the details of that order stored in `wp_postmeta` table using that `post_id` of the order. So we can search in `wp_postmeta` table using `order id` like `post_id='123456'` . There a `paykey` stored in there.